# How to configure the SSIS 'XML Task' component to perform XSLT on multiple XML documents

Tags: xml, xslt, ssis

I need to perform XSLT on multiple XML documents (input) and save the XML documents (output) to a separate folder.

I have the XSL file ready and I am able to use 'XML Task' to alter 1 XML at a time. Unfortunately there are way too many XML files to perform this operation by hand.

'XML Task' has three options (Direct input, Variable & File Connection). 
File Connection gives me the option to select the folder (../XML Candidates)
I then also configure the output through File Connection and select the folder (../XML Transformed)

When running this configuration it fails and I am greeted with the following message:

Error: 0xC002928F at XML Task, XML Task: Property "New Source" has no source Xml text; Xml Text is either invalid, null or empty string.

I have also tried a 'For each loop container'. I have been able to succesfully iterate through the file and write the filepath to a variable. 
When placing an XML task in the Foreach loop container it does not work. It seems like I should be filling the variable with XML data instead of the filepath. Unfortunately I am not sure how to do this

I expect there is way to process a directory full of XML documents to perform XSLT on and write the output (multiple XML files) to a separate directory. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks! :)

Comment: You can try collection() in a variable after that you can use xsl:result-document for save file to another DIR.

Comment: Hi Sandy, thanks for replying. I'm afraid I don't really follow. Could you perhaps phrase your answer in an example?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I created an Azure Logic App to iterate through my container and transform all the XML documents.